Stain not drying on hardwoods
We’re staining our sanded hardwood floors with a Minwax oil based stain. We were staining our floors without heat in the house, while it was cooler and damp outside. It’s been almost 24 hours with our new furnace running at 75 degrees (Tuesday overnight into Wednesday). Stain was applied on Friday night and Saturday night. There are still some areas of tackiness to touch, however, even some of the dry to touch areas are transferring stain to a white rag. Is this to be expected with stain that’s dry to the touch?

Oil products are slow to cure. What does the label say? It would help if you'd state (and link to) the actual product rather than being vague.

It also depends on how it was applied. Personally, I tend to apply two coats, and wipe off any excess before letting it dry. It does mean having to do all three procedures in one area, and backing out of the room in steps. sigh

"We were staining our floors without heat in the house, while it was cooler and damp outside." That can lead to products not curing, sometimes to the point you have to remove them and re-apply in proper conditions. However, with a cold damp house that's only had the furnace running one night, the floors won't be thoughly warmed yet, either, most likely.

https://www.minwax.com/en/wood-stain-color-guide/browse-color-stains/brown/provincial-211-semi-transparent0
It’s an oil based Minwax penetrating stain. Label says dries in 3 hours.
I stained using a lamb skin applicator, one pass, and then removed with a sponge mop (as seen from a professional on YouTube).
